# problema al crear archivo pdf con dompdf, laravel y estilos tailwind

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, tailwind

Buen dia, estoy tratando de generar un `pdf`, utilizando la libreria **Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\Pdf**

El problema surge que al momento de generar el `pdf`, esta **tarda muchos minutos en generar el documento pdf**, pense que era algo de los ciclos o del proceso, pero no es asi. Incluso cuando trate de generar un `pdf` con "HOLA MUNDO" por dentro, tardaba como 5 min, y no cargaba los estilos, estuve leyendo algunos hilos, e indicaban que era por el `css`, y efectivamente, quitando las etiqueteas css de script y link href, generaba, pero sin estilos, revisando vi que como alternativa a

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" ></script>
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

se preferia usar `public_path('css/app.css')`, esto soluciona el tiempo que demora el `pdf` en generarse, **pero los estilos aun estan sin cargarse por completo**, es decir, solo logro ver cambios de formato de texto, tamaños, pero no colores ni subrayados, ni divs de color, anda.

Como puedo solucionar esto? **quiero que me lea los estilos de tailwind**, este es mi segundo dia batallando con esto.

Mi metodo en mi clase componente es:

```
public function makePDF(){
    $pdf= Pdf::loadView('livewire.pdf-invoice',["hola"]);
    $pdf->render();
    return $pdf->stream();
}
```

***Estoy usando:laravel9, tailwind 3.1.8***

EDIT:
mi blade es:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Factura</title>
    <script src="{{ public_path('js/app.js') }}" ></script>
    <link href="{{ public_path('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <span class="text-6xl font-extrabold text-red-900">HOLA mundo</span>
</body>
```

Comment: Las librerias PDF normalmente tienen problemas interpretando archivos CSS externos, te recomendaria usar la etiqueta style y plicar solo los estilos que veas en el compute style a cada elemento que agregas manualmente/dinamicamente. otra forma seria usar una libreria como esta https://github.com/spatie/browsershot y acceder al archivo  y el contenido html

Comment: ahora no veo que pretendes agregando el archivo javascript al PDF... si tu diseño del pdf requiere o depdende de alguna funcionalidad javascript eso jamas va a ocurrir ... recuerda que php ocurre del lado del servidor y javascript en este caso del lado del navegador...

Comment: tienes razón, solo copie el template directo, como te puedo tickear como respuesta? @ArcanisGK507 ? al final si tuve que optar por agregar los estilos dentro de style.

Comment: bueno te acabo de resumir todo en una respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como respuesta a tu pregunta no hay una forma de solucionarlo directamente o un metodo/lihbreria justo para usar.

Las librerias PDF normalmente tienen problemas interpretando archivos CSS externos, te recomendaria usar la etiqueta style y plicar solo los estilos que veas en el compute style a cada elemento que agregas manualmente/dinamicamente. otra forma seria usar una libreria como esta [browsershot](https://github.com/spatie/browsershot) y acceder al archivo y el contenido html.

```
use Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot;

Browsershot::url('https://example.com')->save('example.pdf');
```

Ahora no veo que pretendes agregando el archivo javascript al PDF... si tu diseño del pdf requiere o depdende de alguna funcionalidad javascript eso jamas va a ocurrir ... recuerda que php ocurre del lado del servidor y javascript en este caso del lado del navegador...